# Making better sense of the PTX store caching modes

Tags: caching, cuda, ptx, write-through

I'm looking at the [Store instruction caching modes table](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/parallel-thread-execution/index.html#cache-operators) within the [PTX ISA specification](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/parallel-thread-execution/index.html) (for PTX v2). It provides details regarding four caching modes:

- `.wb`: Cache **write-back** all coherent levels
- `.cg`: Cache at **global** level (cache in L2, not L1)
- `.cs`: Cache **streaming**, likely to be accessed once
- `.wt`: Cache **write-through** (to system memory)

The explanatory text is somewhat confusing for me.

Which modes will result in an immediate change to the L1 cache, the L2 cache and to the global memory, for the line being written to (as opposed to other lines which need to be evicted)? I'll post what I understand from the text as an answer, please correct me if I'm wrong.

Note: Let's ignore local and shared memory for the sake of this question.

Answer (score 2):

(**Edit:** On second reading, I have low confidence in this answer.)

When no evictions are necessary, a store instruction results in the following kinds of writes:

| Mode | L1 | L2 | Global |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| wb | Yes | No | No |
| cg | No | Yes | No |
| cs | Yes | No | No |
| wt | Yes | Yes | Yes |

when all possible evictions occur, the above changes into the following:

| Mode | L1 | L2 | Global |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| wb | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| cg | No | Yes | Yes |
| cs | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| wt | Yes | Yes | Yes |

Caveat: this is based on my understanding of the [PTX ISA documentation](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/parallel-thread-execution/index.html) and nothing else.

Comment: Thank you so much, very useful.